# how to using where expression on a list item property that is a list of string at dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I need a way to search on a list item (list of string) in a list of object. something as below

```
filtered = allExhibitors.where((element) => element.product_categories == element.product_categories?.where((element2) => element2 == filterModel.categoryId)).toList(growable: true);
```

**allExhibitors** is a list of exhibitors (`List<Exhibitor>`) and **product_categories** is list of string (`List<String>`)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contains](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.0/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html).

Something like:

```dart
class Exhibitor {
  List<String> product_categories = [];
}

void f() {
  var allExhibitors = <Exhibitor>[];
  var filterModelId = '';
  var filtered = allExhibitors
      .where((element) => element.product_categories.contains(filterModelId))
      .toList(growable: true);
}
```

Comment: List<String> product_categories property can be NULL. can not initialize it as you.

Comment: `filtered = allExhibitors.where((element) => element.product_categories != null && element.product_categories!.contains(filterModel.categoryId)).toList(growable: true);`

edited yor response and worked. thank you.